# How to set up Gmail in Outlook when the ISP blocks SMTP?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, smtp

In Outlook, I'm setting up a Gmail account and I'm not able to send mails because my ISP is blocking SMTP forward.

Any ways to bypass this?

**EDIT**

I've tried different settings, followed Gmail support [inscructions](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775) and still not working.

> ```
> telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
> telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
> telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
> ```
>
> all of them reply:
>
> > Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could
> >     not open connection to the host, on
> >     port xxx : Connect failed

and I don't have an email acount from my ISP.

Comment: If your ISP is blocking SMTP, then they really should provide some other means to use SMTP, I hope. Are you sure there's no SMTP server available? What ISP is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using your provider's SMTP server, just be sure to have your email client copy the sent items to the Sent Items folder on the server.

(When using Gmail's server, your email client does not have to copy the sent items. More on Gmail IMAP settings at [How should I configure Mail.App and Google Mail?](https://superuser.com/questions/35581/how-should-i-configure-mail-app-and-google-mail/35664#35664))

Answer (score 3):

When you say "Blocks SMTP", I'm assuming you mean "blocks port 25"?

Gmail allows you to use ports 465 or 587 as well, as long as you're using STARTTLS and authenticating before sending the mail.

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12912 has links with walkthroughs showing how to set up most versions of outlook (and most other popular mail clients as well)

Edit: Okay, the extra information makes it fairly clear that *something* is blocking your connection, although it's not clear whether it's your ISP or not. You could try using something like [TCP Traceroute](http://www.goheer.com/products/tcptraceroute/) to verify how far your connection gets before it's dropped

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your email client to send mail out via your ISP's SMTP server even if using an @gmail.com email address.  If necessary, you might have to authenticate with the SMTP server with your ISP based credentials.  Basically, you're asking your ISP to relay for you.